Tapping for monitoring in a safety circuit
I have this machinery piece with a quite long interlock safety line. It's category 1 so it's simply a long series of N/C contacts/limit switches and at the end there's the master safety relay that power the end actuators. No need to worry about masking, cross circuit detection, status pulses or other, the type C standard actually requires a category 1 circuit. Just a 24V PELV line, the interlock chain and the safety relay.
I now need to 'tap' into the line (for monitoring purposes only) and read if the 24V signal is reaching certain places (there are many contacts and finding the opened one is difficult otherwise). Good practice dictates that only safety components should be connected to a safety line but I only need to see if the line is active or not; the result is not safety-relevant, it's only a monitoring one.
Is there a standard describing the actual requirement for safety circuits? In the usual suspects (EN 60204, ISO 14119, 13849, 12100) I can't find details on circuits other than the usual "suitable components" and "wiring best practices and segregation" stuff.
Judging on how this safety line I guess that anything that can't inject a voltage in a point should be safe. The worst could be a ground leak or short (no issue due to PELV), and reading the signal with a low load wouldn't interfere with it. The idea is to attach an optocoupler (they are explicitly listed as components that do not need to be analyzed as shorts) from the line to ground and read on the other side.
Is there an official standard/best practice technical report on what you can/cannot do on a safety circuit line (other than doing a fault analysis/FMEA on the components)?

The issue is that in case of fault a 4060 could leak the supply to the safety line which is a big nono. Except maybe with a protection diode. However my question was more generic, I would like to know if it's there some standard or best practice that listed the allowed/forbidden cases without doing a full analysis each time (which is a pain)
